# canvas not showing text

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

My canvas shows a grid of rectangles in randomly changing colors, but when I want it to end, it does not show the "Bye Bye!" message I added to the canvas. Why is that?

Even if I comment the lines `for i in ...` inside the `__init__` (i.e. the for loop that creates the rectangles in the first place) I don't see the text.

*The text update is done in the start of "update" function, after max iterations.*

*when changing to `self.canvas.create_text(100,100, text="Bye Bye!")`, it does seem to work... but only when no rectangles are showing*

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep
import random 


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, rows = 10, cols = 10, iteration_timer = 1):        

        self.canv_w = 300
        self.canv_h = 300
        self.cell_w = self.canv_w // cols
        self.cell_h = self.canv_h // rows

        self.master = tk.Tk()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, width = self.canv_w, height = self.canv_h)       
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.rect_dict          = {}
        self.iteration_timer    = iteration_timer
        self.iterations         = 0
        self.MAX_ITER           = 10

        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(cols):
                self.rect_dict[(r*self.cell_h, c*self.cell_w)]  = self.canvas.create_rectangle(r    *self.cell_h, c    *self.cell_w,
                                                                                               (1+r)*self.cell_h, (1+c)*self.cell_w,
                                                                                               fill="blue")

        self.master.after(iteration_timer, self.update)
        tk.mainloop()



    def update(self):
        if self.iterations >= self.MAX_ITER:
            self.canvas.create_text(0,0,fill="darkblue", font="Times 100 italic bold", text="Bye Bye!")
            sleep(2)
            self.canvas.delete(tk.ALL)
            self.master.destroy()
            return

        self.iterations += 1

        for k in self.rect_dict:
            r = self.rect_dict[k]
            c = random.choice(['yellow', 'red', 'black', 'blue' , 'white'])
            self.canvas.itemconfig(r, fill=c)


        # call again
        self.master.after(self.iteration_timer, self.update)



def main():
    gui = GUI(rows = 20, cols = 20)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `time.sleep`, everything including the Tkinter mainloop halts. The Tkinter mainloop is responsible for updating the UI, so as long as you don't return to the mainloop you won't see any updates to the UI unless you update it manually. Because you destroy the UI right after the `sleep`, you never see the updated UI with the text.

There's basically two thing you can do, either update manually before calling `sleep`, or changing the `sleep` call to `after`, which returns to the mainloop and schedules the function you pass to it.

To update manually call `self.master.update()` right before `sleep`.

To replace the `sleep` with `after`, just change

```
sleep(2)
self.canvas.delete(tk.ALL)
self.master.destroy()
```

to

```
self.master.after(2000, self.master.destroy)
```

Comment: another question - do you know how can I make the canvas (except for the text) half-transparent?

Comment: I don't think you can do transparency on canvas items. Closest thing is `stipple`. If you add `tags='rect'` to your rectangle creation, you can set the stipple pattern for all rectangles at once with `self.canvas.itemconfig('rect', stipple='gray50')`. You can find the stipple options (which are bitmap images) [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/bitmaps.html).